# CC2640R2L: Transmitting a CCS program to MCU chip via Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, texas-instruments, code-composer

I am considering to use the CC2640R2L Bluetooth wireless MCU by Texas Instrument on a PCB. I only want to use the MCU chip itself, not the whole CC2640R2F LaunchPad.

The question I want to ask is, after I finished programming in CCS (Code Composer Studio by Texas Instrument), can I transmit the program to the wireless MCU by Bluetooth? Does CCS come with the function to transmit program via Bluetooth?

I know that CC2640R2L MCU has JTAG pins. But I want to do all of the communication wirelessly in my design.

Thank you for reading my question.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, a software update is possible via Bluetooth, and the chip is also advertised accordingly. In this context, simply search for "over-the-air upgrade (OTA)", but this is not a function that can be used via CCS.

Such a function usually requires extensive system design requirements, and I know of no public implementations of such a function (in the available SDK for example).

Therefore, in my view, it is best to contact a TI FAE for appropriate help/support.